# How to authorize a web-socket connection in kubernetes in Go?

Tags: go, authentication, kubernetes, websocket, gorilla

so I am trying to implement [Use a WebSocket client to exec commands in a Kubernetes pod](https://jasonstitt.com/websocket-kubernetes-exec) in Go (so I create a WebSocket app to remotely run commands in a container's pod for debugging/monitoring/code-practice) but I am getting:

> dial:tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake exit status
> 1

What am I missing? I am using this as an [example cluster](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/). There is a way to do it by [passing a bearer token](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/47740) but that doesn't look very safe.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

func main() {
    ca, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/george/.minikube/ca.crt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // read client cert
    clientCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/george/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading client cert", err)
    }
    // read client key
    clientKey, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/george/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading client key", err)
    }
    value1 := "ca:" + string(ca)
    value2 := "cert: " + string(clientCert)
    value3 := "key: " + string(clientKey)
    dialer := websocket.DefaultDialer // use default dialer
    dialer.Subprotocols = []string{value1, value2, value3}
    //dialer.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}

    url := "wss://192.168.49.2:30110/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-g4484/exec?command=echo&command=ls&stderr=true&stdout=true"
    //dial websocket

    c, _, err := dialer.Dial(url, nil)

    if err != nil {
        // print response body
        //fmt.Println(response.Body)
        log.Fatal("dial:", err)
    }
    // receive websocket message
    defer c.Close()

}
```

Comment: Don't summarize your errors.   Post them verbetim.

Comment: Are you sure that 192.168.49.2:30110 supports TLS?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Not sure, but I get the same error even doing exactly what the guy in the post did(I install the pod example he provides). I got the ip from minikube, set the corresponding port and then run the command.

Comment: Also, the problem is that kubernetes is not providing any documentation about websockets support. I am thinking that it might be better to use a go client.

Comment: The error indicates that the client connected to a server that does not support TLS.